# PHP ordering json array format

Tags: php, arrays, json, sqlsrv

Im trying to get a json array, from a sql database which needs to be in the above format

```
{
"data":[
{
    "name": "foo",
    "age":"bar"
},
{
    "name": "hello",
    "age":"hi"
},
{
    "name": "bar",
    "age":"foo"
},

]
}
```

My code below return the data like,

```
{
   "0": [
     "name" : "blah",
     "age" : "bleh"
   ],
   "1": [
     "name": "bleh",
     "age" : "blah"
   ],
   "data": []
}
```

## CODE

```
$_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;
include('USERconfig.php');
$dataArray = array("data"=>array());

$sql = "SELECT name, age FROM dataQue";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      array_push($dataArray, 
             array("name"=>$row['name'],"age"=>$row['age']));   


}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($dataArray);
exit();
```

How can i get all the data to be appended within the 'data' array? 
And how can i get rid of the 
 `"0","1","2"` ect.. ?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to push the data into `$dataArray['data']`, not `$dataArray` ...

Comment: wow, how did i miss that. Silly mistake.Thanks @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

`array_push()` will insert data into the array after what you already have in it, I suggest you change the way you insert data in it by just calling back the array in the loop like this

```
$i = 0;
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $dataArray['data'][$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
    $dataArray['data'][$i]['age'] = $row['age'];
    $i++;
}
```

this way all data retrieved from your query will be added to date index. By adding index ($i) will avoid replacing previous register.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
json_decode($dataArray);
```

add **TRUE** to json_decode like :

```
$dataArray = '{"data":[{"name": "foo","age":"bar"},
                       {"name": "hello","age":"hi"},
                       {"name": "bar","age":"foo"}]}';

print_r(json_decode($dataArray, true));
```

the result will be:

```
Array(
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => foo
                [age] => bar
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => hello
                [age] => hi
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => bar
                [age] => foo
            )

    ))
```